# Save recyclerView state between fragments on bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

When i'm switching from another fragment to home fragment, the fragment loads again the data to my recycler view. I want to save the recycler view state and restoring it when the user switch to my home fragment. My problem is that i don't know how to save a custom array list to `onSaveInstanceState()` and then retrieve this from the `onCreateView()` method.

**My HomeFragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    LoadingDialog progressDialog;
    final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    boolean isSearchOpen = false;
    private EditText searchView;
    ArrayList<PostModel> postModelArrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    void loadPosts(View fragmentView, FirebaseUser user, ArrayList<PostModel> postModelArrayList, RecyclerView.Adapter postsAdapter, boolean isRefresh) {
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((HomeActivity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }, 2000);

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.child("posts").getChildren()) {

                    PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
                    postModel.setId(snap.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setImgUrl(snap.child("imgUrl").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setLikes(snap.child("likes").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setName(snap.child("name").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setProfileImgUrl(snap.child("authorProfilePictureURL").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setPostType(snap.child("postType").getValue(String.class));

                    // Show post in recycler adapter only if the user is not blocked
                    if (!snapshot.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("blockedUsers").child(snap.child("name").getValue(String.class)).exists()) {
                        postModelArrayList.add(postModel);
                    }
                }

                if (snapshot.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("blockedUsers").exists()) {
                    System.out.println(snapshot.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("blockedUsers"));
                }


                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // i don't know what i need to do here
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        TextView usernameLoadingScreen = view.findViewById(R.id.textView40);
        ImageButton searchUserBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.searchPersonButton);
        ImageButton notificationsBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.notificationsButton);
        ImageButton searchUserButton = view.findViewById(R.id.enter_search_button);
        View postsOfTheMonthBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.posts_of_the_month_btn);
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        AdView mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
        postModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        final RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(postModelArrayList, getContext(), getActivity());

        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        progressDialog = LoadingDialog.Companion.get(getActivity());

        searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchUserButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ((HomeActivity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        loadPosts(view, user, postModelArrayList, recyclerAdapter, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use a `ViewModel` to save this data instead

Comment: @Zain can you give me please an example to understand what did you mean?

Comment: Please have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e); it's a simple implementation of a `ViewModel`